# How can I get Stack Overflow Trends data?

Tags: support, statistics, trends

I want to use the data from Stack Overflow Trends to create my own plots in Python or MATLAB.

Is it possible to extract data from Stack Overflow Trends so that I can plot it in a similar fashion as seen on https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=flutter ?

[Flutter Stack Overflow Trends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vx55h.png)

Comment: I suspect that the results are based on data that can be obtained from a [SEDE](//data.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Might be better asked on https://stackapps.com/questions

Comment: I don't think this quite fits on Meta, it's still mostly a programming question... I'm not sure why curators were so quick to migrate it. I agree with Chenmunka, [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) is probably the next best site for this.

Comment: @zcoop98 still feels like a resource request for SE specific data. I'm not sure why Stack Apps would be a better fit to answer this then the meta the OP is familiar with.

Comment: @rene You're right, I focused too much on the "so I can plot it" part; this does appear to be more about where to find the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the developer console and inspecting the network calls on https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends you only need to do one HTTP GET call to :

> `https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends/get-data`

and you get a JSON payload as response which include all the data for all tags, for all years. Filtering the right data and representing it is on you.

This what the JSON looks like:

```json
{
  "Year":["2008","2008","2008","2008","2008","2009","2009","2009","2009","2009","2009","2009","2009","2009","2009","2009","2009","2010","2010","2010","2010","2010","2010","2010","2010","2010","2010","2010","2010","2011","2011","2011","2011","2011","2011","2011","2011","2011","2011","2011","2011","2012","2012","2012","2012","2012","2012","2012","2012","2012","2012","2012","2012","2013","2013","2013","2013","2013","2013","2013","2013","2013","2013","2013","2013","2014","2014","2014","2014","2014","2014","2014","2014","2014","2014","2014","2014","2015","2015","2015","2015","2015","2015","2015","2015","2015","2015","2015","2015","2016","2016","2016","2016","2016","2016","2016","2016","2016","2016","2016","2016","2017","2017","2017","2017","2017","2017","2017","2017","2017","2017","2017","2017","2018","2018","2018","2018","2018","2018","2018","2018","2018","2018","2018","2018","2019","2019","2019","2019","2019","2019","2019","2019","2019","2019","2019","2019","2020","2020","2020","2020","2020","2020","2020","2020","2020","2020","2020","2020","2021","2021","2021","2021","2021","2021","2021"],
  "Month":["8","9","10","11","12","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","1","2","3","4","5","6","7"],
  "TagPercents":{
    ".htaccess":[0.10615711252599999,0.086324724839,0.076219512195,0.12746972594,0.100376411543,0.15265233430800002,0.200930018944,0.212293260923,0.21785460573,0.20753387109399998,0.214201563671,0.239838031459,0.342391807273,0.241486825212,0.26936961955,0.23078940466800002,0.30717452855300004,0.275741475553,0.276584740617,0.31036742876900003,0.311808489237,0.238247428671,0.343170899107,0.30938239332899997,0.319175831121,0.37824592563299997,0.340500662084,0.336505827472,0.375890933799,0.374489475337,0.363587885251,0.37727584936799996,0.39164216715600003,0.324051848295,0.33406219630699996,0.373584116199,0.342215988779,0.394729090159,0.41109562914400005,0.404512149154,0.40458464895699997,0.450897052357,0.44491542562200004,0.42108102438,0.38858492912200004,0.430064248766,0.401655679901,0.444730404287,0.461506784149,0.488915882174,0.451666945887,0.41190241916299997,0.45407667366499993,0.411824330785,0.42192985334099997,0.386216466234,0.39989695188299995,0.40702785371,0.400848557768,0.427655833475,0.48901913706600003,0.527699700788,0.540032488876,0.533891621702,0.545605216518,0.58568490682000007,0.52574107118999991,0.512469447082,0.47680279806599996,0.458228523731,0.472247021518,0.513290144603,0.51480366981399994,0.498983329009,0.46452825155199995,0.452943228709,0.490540950487,0.490252380232,0.466397881527,0.45326408318399997,0.436225799791,0.471869132074,0.43599208259699995,0.44071893240000004,0.424494319756,0.451331938238,0.41919559763599995,0.39665075549799994,0.405842735939,0.41897501153000005,0.404005857016,0.360507906707,0.364870120565,0.366360745695,0.385923099629,0.349793769796,0.393211690976,0.414337852848,0.341683683741,0.325110623924,0.32381567988800003,0.389173889969,0.37080754282399997,0.343317568751,0.350013548911,0.319493999351,0.30033427034599997,0.30632682716,0.30588168405399996,0.31231724464,0.29407753923499996,0.244666567208,0.28716895800599995,0.30698388334599996,0.277453752216,0.22934976714799998,0.21488147361399998,0.21202137079,0.20609518326100001,0.20761990365900002,0.20507856037299999,0.20043579070800002,0.199015594786,0.184243793539,0.195650022457,0.19553110292999998,0.188439187098,0.20371434998800003,0.185967656084,0.17997644917800001,0.154850621263,0.166779415803,0.196334595484,0.167985140345,0.155610589466,0.142922284306,0.13777250030399998,0.16148761012,0.176395013715,0.14381251491299998,0.125999328737,0.128359319803,0.132880641573,0.129345776316,0.13223393063799999,0.13655011210200002,0.159288669107,0.146310314257,0.17577803912599999,0.165128469949,0.141397180893,0.15834300985,0.149451403992,0.145577467568,0.13502496687999999,0.14401823396],
    ".net":[ etc...] 
...
```